# Problems with Raspberry Pi Configuration

Tags: raspi-config, sudo

i'm pretty new with Raspberry Pi. 
I tried to sudo raspi-config, but it tells me

> The boot partition is not mounted - cannot configure. Note that
>   raspi-config is intended for use on Raspbian only and cannot be
>   guaranteed to work on other operating systems.

I want to get SSH-access to Raspberry Pi.

I also could not do the sudo command on the Raspberry Pi Terminal. It tells me

> sudo: not found

The operating system Linux RPi3 4.6.3-17583-g7d976fc.
The model is Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the result of `cat /etc/os-release`

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.